# Trying to install python3-pip, which has no installation candidate

Tags: 20.04, python, python3, pip

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Desktop

My default Python version was 2.7.18 for some reason. I would like to update it to Python3 so I can install python3-pip onto my desktop.

After running:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 20
```

I get:

```
 update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.8 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode
```

My python version is:
Python 3.8.5

The issue is still that when I run:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

Does anyone have any recommendations?

In my bin for python i have:
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python2

Comment: `sudo apt update` is necessary.  Also, `python-is-python3` is also needed here.  Make sure you ran `sudo apt update` **BEFORE** you try and install things or mess with things manually yourself (because that WILL BREAK things)

Comment: I did read that in other threads and every time that I open up the terminal I run sudo apt-get update then sudo apt-get upgrade before I start.

python-is-python3: command not found

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may have to enable the universe repository first.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then run the following command to synchronize your package database.

```
sudo apt update
```

Finaly install `pip3` with

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```